# set the position of a view relative to its superview using autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I had the exact problem like in 
[Using iOS 6 Auto Layout to position view relative to size of superview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175815/using-ios-6-auto-layout-to-position-view-relative-to-size-of-superview). But there hasn't been a proper answer.

I want to set the position of a label at a distance a third of the height of its superview from the top.

Is there a way to do this? Either using auto layout in IB or setting constraints in code would be fine.

Comment: Have you tried using subViewYConstraint.constant = superView.bounds.size.height / 3.0; ?

Comment: @Zhang I just tried it but it doesn't work so well. When I tried 3.0, the label is positioned at the center. Does the height under the navigation bar count? I've already uncheck the "under top bars" in the inspector.